# With Android 12 and below Using BT headset the output voice is breaking - Android development

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth, android-12

I have an one app , in there i am using BT to take input from user using voice recognization. & based on user input i am giving some message to user using MP3 file or using TTS. But the issue is the voice coming to BT is breaking with android version 12 and below. If i am not Using any BT logic that time if BT is connected , that time its take input from mobile speaker & give output to BT without any breaking.

First i am checking the Bluetooth is connected with mobile or not and whatever Bluetooth is connected i am fetching the id of that Bluetooth device.

**Permissions:**

```
   String[] PERMISSIONS = {  //for Android 11
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,


  };
  /*permission for android 
  version 11*/
  String[] BACKGROUNDLOCAION ={
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
 };
 /*permission for android version 12 and Above*/
 String[] PERMISSIONS12AndAbove ={
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
 };
 /*Permission for android version android 10 and below*/
 String [] PERMISSIONS10AndBelow={
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH
 };
```

This Method i am calling first inside Oncreate & after that whenever i got BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED through BroadcastReceiver

**Code to fetch Id of connected Bluetooth headset:**

```
 private void bluetoothListener() {
   deviceconnected=0;
   BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener serviceListener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {

                if (profile == A2DP || profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
                    List<BluetoothDevice> devices = proxy.getConnectedDevices();
                    System.out.println("Listed device : "+devices.size());
                    if(devices.size() >0){
                        BluetoothDevice device = devices.get(0);
                        if (proxy.getConnectionState(device) == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED &&                   deviceconnected<1) {
                            // Device is currently connected and in use
                            deviceconnected = 1;
                            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                            String deviceName = device.getName();
```

```
   deviceAddress = device.getAddress();
```

```
                        }
                        else{
                            if(proxy.getConnectionState(device) ==  BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED){
                                setAudioRoutingToDefault(getApplicationContext());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        if(devices.size()==0){
                            setAudioRoutingToDefault(getApplicationContext());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        };
        bluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(getApplicationContext(), serviceListener,     BluetoothProfile.A2DP);
        //bluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(getApplicationContext(), serviceListener,    BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);
}
```

Whenever i am activating voice recognization that time i am checking the deviceAddress and based on that i am calling the method

**Code for check the Bluetooth state & connected device id:**

`private void startSpeechRecognition() {
//For Bluetooth

```
     if (bluetoothAdapter != null && bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            if(deviceAddress!="") {
                setAudioRoutingToBluetooth(getApplicationContext(), deviceAddress);
            }
            else{
                setAudioRoutingToDefault(getApplicationContext());
            }
        }
        else{
            setAudioRoutingToDefault(getApplicationContext());
        }
```

```
    speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(MainActivity.this);
    speechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, /*600000*/5000);
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, /*600000*/5000);
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODE  L_FREE_FORM);
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, new Locale("en", "IN"));
    speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle bundle) {
            System.out.println("onReadyForSpeech" + bundle);
        }
        ....
```

}
`

**code for set Bluetooth device as input & output:**

`private void setAudioRoutingToBluetooth(Context context, String deviceid) {
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
System.out.println("Device id"+deviceid);
String id = deviceid;
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"communicate with BT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// Set audio routing to connected Bluetooth device
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
audioManager.startBluetoothSco();

```
        audioManager.setParameters("input_device=" + id);
        audioManager.setParameters("input_device=" + id);
```

```
   }`
```

so using this code i am able to give input from Bluetooth headset , and it is correct . but in return the output is breaking.

**code for communicate with Mobile speaker when Bluetooth device is null or Bluetooth is not enable:**
`private void setAudioRoutingToDefault(Context context) {
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

```
    // Revert to default audio routing (e.g., mobile speaker or earpiece)
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
    audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
    audioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
    System.out.println("Mobile speaker connected");
```

```
      audioManager.setParameters("input_device=1;output_device=0");
```

```
}`
```